# Modifying the content od divs elements individually with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays

I am trying to go through and send the content (IPv4 addresses) of multiple divs (limited to 3 for the sake of simplicity) sharing the same class "ip" via ajax to a php file returning me the corresponding countries but I am having problems getting the good and individual value for each of them.
Firebug shows me that the values are send correctly each one after the other but then I only get the IP resolution of the last IP for all 3 divs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>form test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form" action="">
        <div class="inp"><input type="checkbox" /><div class="ip">57.20.123.87</div></div>
        <div class="inp"><input type="checkbox" /><div class="ip">54.220.223.47</div></div>
        <div class="inp"><input type="checkbox" /><div class="ip">37.120.23.97</div></div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".ip").each(function(i) {
                var ipfromT = new Array();
                ipfromT = $(this).html();
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost/ic/jsonquery.php',
                    data: "ipfromT="+ipfromT,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {
                        var ipfield = data[0];
                        var iprevealed = data[1];
                        $("[class='ip']").html("<b>sent IP:</b> "+ipfield+" <b>Location:</b> "+iprevealed);
                        }
                });
            });
        }); 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have searched a few hours to create an array with the various values, send them via ajax all at once and then put them back but I cannot manage to do it so I ask for advice/ help/ suggestions.

Thank you very much

Comment: You're looping over each div, building a new array each time, and then assigning the IP to the array while changing the array to a string (you use `push()` to add to an array, not `=`). You should build your array separately, then make your AJAX call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `$('[class="ip"]')` on your `success` callback, instead use a cached var for current iteration element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ip").each(function(i) {
        var ipfromT = new Array();
        ipfromT = $(this).html();
        var $ip = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/ic/jsonquery.php',
            data: "ipfromT="+ipfromT,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                var ipfield = data[0];
                var iprevealed = data[1];
                $ip.html("<b>sent IP:</b> "+ipfield+" <b>Location:</b> "+iprevealed);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

With `$('[class="ip"]')` you are getting all concurrences of elements with a class of "ip" on the document, not just the one you are trying to get with Ajax. That's why on the iteration you must get the current one you are working with, and use it on the callback function of the Ajax request.

Comment: Thank you very much! Works like a charm! Just out of curiosity, how should I proceede to submit at once the whole list of IPs and then reassociate the output of ajax in the document?

Comment: Maybe sending an array with your IPs to the server, which respond with another array of IP info arranged in the same order of received IPs. Iterate over those IP info and fill in your `.ip` objects based on the index of the iteration: `$('.ip:eq('+ index +')').html('IP info: '+ info);`